# Swagger UI shows nested model objects when using ZoneId and jackson-datatype-jsr310

Tags: spring, jackson, swagger, swagger-ui, springfox

I am developing a REST API with Spring, springfox, Jackson and my model class contains a `ZoneId` as property:

```
@JsonProperty
private ZoneId timeZone;
```

I included *jackson-datatype-jsr310* version *2.9.0.pr4* in my dependencies, so it is serializing and deserializing fine as expected. But my swagger-ui shows a lot of model objects like `ZoneId`, `ZoneOffset`, `ZoneOffsetTransition` etc now which is very confusing since the zone ID is serialized as simple string. Same situation in generated API spec. **How can I prevent swagger to expose these (unused) model objects?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try [`@ApiModelProperty`](http://docs.swagger.io/swagger-core/current/apidocs/io/swagger/annotations/ApiModelProperty.html) setting `dataType` to `string`:

```java
@JsonProperty
@ApiModelProperty(dataType = "string")
private ZoneId timeZone;
```

If `dataType` gets ignored, you can use [`Docket`](http://springfox.github.io/springfox/javadoc/current/springfox/documentation/spring/web/plugins/Docket.html):

```java
@Bean
public Docket configureDocket() {
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
            .directModelSubstitute(ZoneId .class, String.class);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I took your second solution because it's easier for me to not annotate properties with swagger annotations.